# Where is the documentation for Perl's builtin `Internals::` package?

Tags: perl, module, internals

When using `keys %::` to get a list of the currently loaded root namespaces, the `Internals::` package is loaded by default (along with `UNIVERSAL::` and a few others).  However, I haven't found any documentation for the functions in `Internals::`

`keys %{Internals::}` returns `SvREFCNT hv_clear_placeholders hash_seed SvREADONLY HvREHASH rehash_seed`

All of these can probably be looked up in Perl's C API docs, but is there any Perl level documentation for them?  Is the package stable?  It's used by several core modules (`Hash::Util` for one), so I imagine it is, but the lack of documentation is a bit troubling.

I didn't see `Internals.pm` in the Perl distribution (different name maybe?), and it is not the `Internals` module up on CPAN.

Note: I fully understand that the functions in `Internals::` are potentially dangerous, and I do not have any particular use in mind.  I was reading through `Hash::Util`'s source and came across it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC the code is not Internals.pm but [libinternals.c](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#bT5GSV0pcww/libinternals.c&q=internals.c%20lang:c%20SvREFCNT&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc). It looks like they used to be in [universal.c in Perl 5.8](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#E4XixW5gvCc/pub/CPAN/src/perl-5.8.1.tar.gz|NJKdlW8DkIY/perl-5.8.1/universal.c&q=universal.c%20lang:c%20SvREFCNT) but got migrated out.

As per 03/2009 and Perl 5.10 they were not documented as per [this perlmonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=747345).

Also, in the same thread, [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) states:

> Undocumented things in universal.c
>   should not be depended on; they should
>   only be used by core modules. They
>   aren't documented on purpose, to allow
>   them to be changed whenever and
>   however necessary. For those purposes,
>   the code is good enough documentation.

Comment: the comments in `universal.c` are great: `/* This is dangerous stuff. */` ... `/* I hope you really know what you are doing. */`

Comment: "...the code is good enough documentation" -- that doesn't prevent people from writing code against the current implementation and seeing it break when changes are made.

Comment: The link you provided earlier - http://perlbin.sourceforge.net/perlcompiler/perl.internals.pdf - looks interesting, although it appears quite outdated.

Comment: @Ether - it does not seem to be centered on explaining internals:: module (which probably geled together after that was written?) and so, while interesting, i deemed it to be somewhat irrelevant to this Q.

Comment: @Eric - in an interesting timing, I'm releasing an initial version of Perl module today which has a comment: `# Now, for the voodoo. DON'T MESS WITH THIS CODE IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING - deep Perl magic!`. In reality the magic is more David Copperfield than deep voodoo, but the target audience is pretty far from people likely to be reading libinternals.c :)

Comment: @DVK: suggestion: also explain your voodoo in comments, or you will be scratching your head in a few years wondering why on earth you did it the way you did and what you were thinking.  Trust me. :)

Comment: @Ether - of course. I always do, voodoo or not. I'm a software developer, not a coder. Though in this case the voodoo is embarassingly easy as far as I'm concerned :)